# UISegmentedControl switch views in uitableviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

I have the following scenario:

```
UITabBarController
--tab1
--tab2
----UINavigationController (with a UITableViewController and 3 rows)
------pushedViewController
--tab3
--tab4
--tab5
```

Ok, so, when user clicks on an option in the UINavigationViewController it pushes "pushedViewController", and in that viewcontroller I want to have a segmented control like the one on the App Store https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrdxL.png

How can I do this?

I already checked

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559794/changing-views-from-uisegmentedcontrol
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280653/uisegmentedcontrol-to-switch-views-in-uitabbarcontroller
http://www.astroryan.com/?p=19
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723094/using-uisegmentedcontrol-to-switch-between-two-views
```

This could help me but I can't figure out how
[Switch between UIViewControllers using UISegmentedControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555218/switch-between-uiviewcontrollers-using-uisegmentedcontrol)

And this user asked the same but it doesn't have the full code
[Recreating Segmented Control from iPhone App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128659/recreating-segmented-control-from-iphone-app-store)

Answer (score 0):

The pushedViewController can contain a UIScrollView framed to fill the screen.  Set paging enabled, and give it three big subviews, like this:

```
CGFloat width = self.view.bounds.width;
CGFloat height = self.view.bounds.height;

// it's easier to do all this this in xib/storyboard, but to illustrate...

self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,width,height);
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width*3.0, height);  // this must be done in code
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

UIView *subviewA, *subviewB, subviewC;

subviewA.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, height);
subviewB.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, width, width, height);
subviewB.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 2.0*width, width, height);

[self.scrollView addSubview:subviewA];
[self.scrollView addSubview:subviewB];
[self.scrollView addSubview:subviewC];

// then when the segmented control changes ...

- (IBAction)segmentedControlChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {

    NSInteger page = sender.selectedSegmentIndex;
    CGFloat contentOffsetX = page*self.view.bounds.width;
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(contentOffsetX, 0.0) animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Nice, I'll give it try but I think that this is going to be a little problematic because I want to add UIViewControllers that have UITableView and I don't know exactly how are they going to behave.

Comment: Yes.  I meant to add something to my answer about that.  This is for full screen views, controlled by the same view controller.  3 view controllers controlled by a segmented control is really a tab bar controller.  If you want the tabs at the top, want them to look like a segmented button, want the VCs to slide, etc. Then you're basically deciding to implement your own container view controller (probably not even a tab bar vc subclass).  This is a pretty large undertaking.  Best of luck.